# Children's Motrin and Advil

Tags: kashrut-kosher, medicine

Recently it was publicized that certain lots of Children's Tylenol contain a non-kosher form of glycerin, and therefore should not be used in non-urgent situations. Does anyone have information about the status of liquid Advil and Motrin?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the warning you are talking about: [Kashrus Alerts](http://www.star-k.org/alerts/alerts-OCTOBER2010.htm)

It seems that it only affects the Tylenol version that's produced in Canada. However, it's best that you contact the Star-K for further information: [Contact STAR-K](http://www.star-k.org/cons-abou-contact.htm)

If you do get further information, please come back here and post it so that others can see it in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I just called Star-K, and they said that liquid Motrin is OK, but liquid Advil has problematic ingredients (glycerin, poly-80). They also said that if I need to use the Advil, I should do bittul by mixing it in 2 oz. of water per teaspoon.